# How to solve Java.lang.IllegalAccessError

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I am trying to have a final build in my application but i am encountering the following error :

```
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.KaptContext (in unnamed module @0x72514ce0) cannot access class com.sun.tools.javac.util.Context (in module jdk.compiler) because module jdk.compiler does not export com.sun.tools.javac.util to unnamed module @0x72514ce0
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.KaptContext.\<init\>(KaptContext.kt:29)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.KaptContextForStubGeneration.\<init\>(KaptContextForStubGeneration.kt:40)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.AbstractKapt3Extension.contextForStubGeneration(Kapt3Extension.kt:287)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.AbstractKapt3Extension.analysisCompleted(Kapt3Extension.kt:171)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.ClasspathBasedKapt3Extension.analysisCompleted(Kapt3Extension.kt:102)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.analyzeFilesWithJavaIntegration$invokeExtensionsOnAnalysisComplete(TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.kt:112)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.analyzeFilesWithJavaIntegration(TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.kt:122)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.analyzeFilesWithJavaIntegration$default(TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.kt:86)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler$analyze$1.invoke(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:540)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler$analyze$1.invoke(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:531)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.messages.AnalyzerWithCompilerReport.analyzeAndReport(AnalyzerWithCompilerReport.kt:113)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.analyze(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:531)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.compileModules$cli(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:188)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.compileModules$cli$default(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:154)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:169)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:52)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.kt:90)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.kt:44)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool.exec(CLITool.kt:98)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.runCompiler(IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.kt:386)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.runCompiler(IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.kt:110)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.compileIncrementally(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:303)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.compileImpl$rebuild(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:99)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.compileImpl(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:124)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.compile(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:74)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImplBase.execIncrementalCompiler(CompileServiceImpl.kt:607)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImplBase.access$execIncrementalCompiler(CompileServiceImpl.kt:96)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.compile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:1659)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
at java.rmi/sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:360)
at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:712)
at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:587)
at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:828)
at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:705)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:704)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

I have tried various solutions available on Stack overflow but none of them works, i tried changing my TargetSdk and CompileSdk but it didnt work,.

**Here is my build.gradle(app level) file**

```
plugins {
id 'com.android.application'
id 'kotlin-android'
id 'kotlin-kapt'
id 'dagger.hilt.android.plugin'
}

android {
compileSdk 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.plcoding.cleanarchitecturenoteapp"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 34
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary true
        }
    }
    
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
        useIR = true
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion compose_version
        kotlinCompilerVersion '1.5.21'
    }
    packagingOptions {
        resources {
            excludes += '/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}'
        }
    }

}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.10.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.0'
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui:$compose_version"
    //noinspection GradleDependency
    implementation "androidx.compose.material:material:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview:$compose_version"
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.6.1'
    implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.7.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4:$compose_version"
    debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:$compose_version"
    
    // Compose dependencies
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-compose:2.6.1"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:2.7.0-beta02"
    //noinspection GradleDependency
    implementation "androidx.compose.material:material-icons-extended:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.hilt:hilt-navigation-compose:1.1.0-alpha01"
    
    // Coroutines
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.6.4'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.6.4'
    
    //Dagger - Hilt
    implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.44"
    kapt "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.37"
    implementation "androidx.hilt:hilt-lifecycle-viewmodel:1.0.0-alpha03"
    kapt "androidx.hilt:hilt-compiler:1.0.0"
    
    // Room
    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:2.5.2"
    kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:2.5.2"
    
    // Kotlin Extensions and Coroutines support for Room
    implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:2.5.2"

}
```

**and here is my build.gradle(module level)**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
ext {
compose_version = '1.0.2'
}
repositories {
google()
mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.4"
classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.5.21"
classpath "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin:2.38.1"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }

}

task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Please help me, as i tried to build an application which is a simple notes app from youtube.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade Kotlin Gradle Plugin Version to 1.7.0+ and try.
Kapt works well with JDK 16+ when Kotlin is 1.7.0 or higher.

```
classpath 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.9.0'
```

[Kotlin Gradle](https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/org.jetbrains.kotlin.android)